# How to configure NGINX as proxy for local SMTP server?

Tags: nginx, proxy, smtp, passthrough

I am doing some testing with the NodeJS smtp-server module. It exposes a listening SMTP server on any specified port.  SMTP usually runs on port 25, but in order to run the Node app as a non-root user, I am prevented from binding to ports below 1000.

Since I am already using nginx on this machine, I thought the simplest way to get around this would be to bind the server internally to a higher port, for example, 2500.  Then use nginx to proxy the SMTP port (25) and directly pass through traffic to the internal listening port.

**How can I configure nginx to proxy/passthrough incoming SMTP connections on port 25 to the port on which smtp-server is listening?**  In this case, incoming TCP connections on port 25 should be directly forwarded to localhost:2500.

Note that the smtp-server app already handles SMTP authentication, TLS, etc, so nginx should not attempt to do those operations.  It should just pass the traffic directly through.

Comment: Just answered this [here](https://serverfault.com/a/1120748) for a related, but not duplicate, question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I figured it out:

Edit the /etc/nginx/nginx.conf file and add the following:

```
stream
{
        server
        {
                listen 25;
                proxy_pass 127.0.0.1:2500;
        }
}
```

Comment: not worked for me